# Downgrad Node Version to 10.13.0

Tags: node.js, npm

I was trying to downgrade my current node version

What is the best to downgrade node version from 14.4.0 to 10.13.0?

Please advice

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling node and installing the desired version?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) or [nvm](http://nvm.sh/). These applications  help you manage multiple versions of Node.js.

Just run `sudo npm install -g n` and then `sudo n 10.13.0` and you should be good to go. If you're not on Linux ignore the `sudo` part.

You'll know it worked if you run `node --version` and it says `v10.13.0`.